# How to know keyboard suggestion is displayed or not?

Tags: ios, keyboard, autosuggest

I want to set a flag when keyboard suggestion is displayed but I couldn't find any event for that.
Do you know how to get it?

Comment: can you give an example or a context?

Comment: Now I am using UITextFieldDelegate. I can get keyboard input with 


`- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`

When user use keyboard suggest, **replacementString** will have the word user selected. But I don't supposed multiple stings in it. So if I can know that the input is done by keyboard suggestion I can handle it.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: So title may not be adequate. It should be **How to know key input by keyboard or keyboard suggestion?** or something like that.